# I want to pull attributes into a label using a JPG

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, fields-attributes

This is my first post so I'll try to be specific as possible but also as short as possible. I have created a "Bore Profile" jpg. In ArcMap, I brought into a feature class through labeling. I want to be able to pull attributes from the feature class to "fill in the blanks" on the bore profile sheet.

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Below is an image showing the bore profile that I created. The attributes that I want to fill in, inside ArcMap, are in red.

[image]

Below is an image of the bore profile as a label in ArcMap. I need to use Expression builder, or scripting, to pull in attributes to populate as shown above. Or, perhaps through a table?

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this would be great.